# Android accelerometer sampling rate statistic

Tags: android, accelerometer, wakelock

I am struggling with the accelerometer sampling rate of my app.
So I decided to develope a little app just for testing the sampling rate.

Are there any mistakes in my code? The sampling rate is pretty much changing :-/

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
private TextView infotext;

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private long nanoNow;
private long nanoOld;
private long nanodiffsum=0;
private int i=0;
private int values=2000;
private long[] nanodiff=new long[values];

DescriptiveStatistics myDescrStat = new DescriptiveStatistics();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int tid=android.os.Process.myTid()
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

    infotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

        if (i==0){
        nanoOld=event.timestamp;
        }

        if (i == values) {

        for (int i=1; i<nanodiff.length; i++){
            myDescrStat.addValue(nanodiff[i]);
            nanodiffsum+=nanodiff[i];
        }

        infotext.setText(
            "Average:" + nanodiffsum / values + "ms\n" + " = " + (double) 1000 / (nanodiffsum /values) + "Hz"  + "\n" +
                    "mean: " + 1000 / myDescrStat.getMean() + "\n" +
                    "std:" + 1000 / myDescrStat.getStandardDeviation() + "\n" +
                    "max:" + 1000 / myDescrStat.getMin() + "\n" +
                    "min:" + 1000 / myDescrStat.getMax() + "\n");

        mWakeLock.release();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }else{
        nanoNow=event.timestamp;
        nanodiff[i]=(nanoNow-nanoOld)/1000000;
        if (i%20==0)
            infotext.setText("Aktuell: " + nanodiff[i] + "ms" + " = " + Math.round((double)1000/ nanodiff[i]) + "Hz" );
        nanoOld=nanoNow;
        i++;

        }
    }
}
```

Kindly regards,
Arthur

Answer (score 2):

After a cursory look at your code I cannot see anything wrong with it (except perhaps the overzealous update of the thread priority, which makes sense in a testing app but I wouldn't use without a good reason in actual production code).

As for the irregular rate of the the SensorManager's data (**spoiler alert:** the same behavior applies to other sensor streams ;-) ), it is meant to be that way, and the frequency specified with `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` is meant to be only a hint (which is the reason why actually you receive the time of the measurement with such accuracy at each event). This is stated in the official documentation:

**rateUs** *:   The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. 
Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster.* Source: [registerListener reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int))

For one part, keep in mind that Android is Linux at the core, and linux is not a real-time system (and therefore can't provide data with realtime accuracy); on the other side, *Android has to cope with a lot of different hardware implementations* (and sensor brands), therefore the Android developers team has probably done a wise choice to avoid any kind of commitment about the ratio of the sensor data.

Those are my 50 cents, if you want to get serious about Android Sensors programming I would suggest this book:

[Professional Android Sensor Programming (Greg Milette, Adam Stroud)](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-Sensor-Programming.productCd-1118183487.html)

I read about 1/4 of it and so far, so good (I'm in no way related to the publisher or the author).

Hope this helps